# virtual_memory meaning for process in container

Tags: docker, linux-kernel, containers, shared-memory

In the old days, virtual memory was not to be trusted, as the same library was loaded only once in memory, but added to all programs that use it.

For a process in a container, is the virtual memory the real memory used?

Comment: What do you mean by virtual vs real memory? How do you make that distinction. Or do you mean shared memory?

Comment: The virtual memory as defined by top: The  total  amount  of  virtual  memory  used  by the task.  It includes all code, data and shared libraries  plus  pages  that have been swapped out.

Answer (score 0):

Resources in Linux containers are managed via [cgroups](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/cgroups.7.html),

> A cgroup is a collection of processes that are bound to a set of
>     limits or parameters defined via the cgroup filesystem.

Particularly, regarding the memory cgroup,

> memory (since Linux 2.6.25; CONFIG_MEMCG)
>     The memory controller supports reporting and limiting of
>     process memory, kernel memory, and swap used by cgroups.